# defaultdict equivalent for lists

Tags: python, collections, containers, defaultdict

Is there\How would you build an equivalent of python's very useful [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)?

Imagined usage of such a container:

```
>>> a = collections.defaultlist(0)
>>> a[2]=7
>>> a[4]='x'
>>> a
[0,0,7,0,'x']
```

**UPDATE:** I've added a [follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749542/creating-a-defaultlist-for-python) to add even more functionality to this construct

Comment: @Josh Lee: Did you read the tags at all? No JavaScript at all-- this is a Python question.

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: @PlatinumAzure Did you see the smiley at all?

Comment: @CatPlusPlus - Half because I need it for something specific, half out of curiosity :)

Comment: @Jonathan: You more than likely do *not* need it.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus - Due to a series of annoying constraints, which I should definitely remove by a future refactoring effort, I _currently_ need _exactly_ this

Comment: And what is the expected behaviour for `a[-1] = 'x'` ?

Comment: Please feel free to explain these "annoying constraints".

Comment: constraints which should be refactored out (I know guys, please don't give me a rough time about it): This object travels around the system where many modules (consumers) depend on it having at least a tuple behavior, giving semantic meaning to items' index and to the list's length. Producers of this object don't know in advance its length and iterate over various sources while building it. Basically I'm trying to encapsulate a reoccuring list building logic which I could rewrite several times, but why? especially after I've discovered the incredible ease of using `defaultdict`...

Comment: @wim - I think Finn's answer gives an intuitive approach to assignment to `-1` index by keeping it simple - simple access index `-1` without any special behavior

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this would be a bit confusing to use; however, here's my first thought on how to do it:

```
class defaultlist(list):
    def __init__(self, fx):
        self._fx = fx

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        while len(self) <= index:
            self.append(self._fx())
        list.__setitem__(self, index, value)
```

This takes a callable (I think that's how defaultdict works) for the default value.

When I run:

```
a = defaultlist(int)
print a
a[2] = 7
a[4] = 'x'
print a
```

I get back:

```
[]
[0, 0, 7, 0, 'x']
```

Comment: The question seems to want the default to be a value, rather than a callable (so in that respect, different than `defaultdict`).  It would be trivial to adapt yours to fit the question (append `self._fx` rather than `self._fx()`).

Comment: Now try `a[4]='x'` `a[2]=7` and see the bug in this code. Easy to fix though.

Comment: It wasn't my fix - thank Ethan.

Comment: @MarkRansom: finding the bug is usually the harder part.

Comment: You're right, `defaultdict` does take only callables, therefor so should `defaultlist`. You could always use `lambda:0` instead of `0`

Comment: @Jonathan: If `0` is what you want, just use `int`.

Comment: To mirror `defaultdict` properly, it should also handle `__getitem__` e.g. if `x = defaultlist(list)` I want to do `x[3].append(2)` or `x[5] += [0, 1]`

Answer (score 4):

If all you need is *indexed access* and not slicing / append, etc, then just use a `defaultdict`.

(if you really want perl / js semantics on this, you could subclass list `__get__` and `__set__`)

Answer (score 2):

My proposal:

```
def xtend(f):
    def wrap(self, index, *args):
        if len(self) <= index:
            self.extend([self._gen()] * (index - len(self) + 1))
        return f(self, index, *args)
    return wrap

class defaultlist(list):
    def __init__(self, gen, lst = []):
        list.__init__(self, lst)
        self._gen = gen

    __setitem__ = xtend(list.__setitem__)
    __getitem__ = xtend(list.__getitem__)
```

Results:

```
>>> a = defaultlist(int, [1, 2, 3])
>>> a[10] = 'x'
>>> a[2] = 7
>>> print a
[1, 2, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'x']
```

Answer (score 2):

A slightly enhanced version from answer by @Finn.

```
class defaultlist(list):
    """List returning default value when accessing uninitialized index.

    Original implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8719940/315168
    """

    def __init__(self, fx):
        self._fx = fx

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        while len(self) <= index:
            self.append(self._fx())
        list.__setitem__(self, index, value)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        """Allows self.dlist[0] style access before value is initialized."""
        while len(self) <= index:
            self.append(self._fx())
        return list.__getitem__(self, index)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest way is using a dict:

```
>>> a = {}
>>> a[2] = 7
>>> a[4] = 'x'
>>> [a[i] if i in a else 0 for i in xrange(max(a) + 1)]
[0, 0, 7, 0, 'x']
```