# creating a defaultlist in python

Tags: python, list, subclassing

I'm trying to create a list equivalent for the very useful [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). The following design works nicely:

```
class defaultlist(list):
    def __init__(self, fx):
        self._fx = fx
    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        while len(self) <= index:
            self.append(self._fx())
        list.__setitem__(self, index, value)
```

Here's how you use it:

```
>>> dl = defaultlist(lambda:'A')
>>> dl[2]='B'
>>> dl[4]='C'
>>> dl
['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C']
```

What should I add to the defaultlist so as to support the following behavior?

```
>>> dl = defaultlist(dict)
>>> dl[2]['a'] = 1
>>> dl
[{}, {}, {'a':1}]
```

Comment: This question is a follow-up to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719558/defaultdict-equivalent-for-lists)

Comment: I assume you're just looking for the method to overload for item access (as opposed to item assignment)?

Comment: Wouldn't `dl[2] = {'a', 1}` make more sense?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

On the example you give, you first try to retrieve a non-existing value on the list, as you do `dl[2]['a']`, Python first retrieve the third (index 2) element on the list, then proceed to get the element named 'a' on that object - therefore you have to implement your automatic extending behavior to the `__getitem__` method as well, like this:

```
class defaultlist(list):
    def __init__(self, fx):
        self._fx = fx
    def _fill(self, index):
        while len(self) <= index:
            self.append(self._fx())
    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        self._fill(index)
        list.__setitem__(self, index, value)
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        self._fill(index)
        return list.__getitem__(self, index)
```

Comment: I also hoped something simple like this would be enough, but keep in mind that index could also be a slice. For example `lst = defaultlist(lambda:None); lst[:]` will throw `TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'slice'`

Comment: To also support slices I used something like this in my code: `idx = (idx if type(idx) is int else ((idx.stop if idx.stop is not None else len(lst))-(idx.step if idx.step is not None else 1)) if type(idx) is slice else len(lst)-1)`

Answer (score 16):

There is a python package available:

```
$ pip install defaultlist
```

Added indicies are filled with None by default.

```
>>> from defaultlist import defaultlist
>>> l = defaultlist()
>>> l
[]
>>> l[2] = "C"
>>> l
[None, None, 'C']
>>> l[4]
>>> l
[None, None, 'C', None, None]
```

Slices and negative indicies are supported likewise

```
>>> l[1:4]
[None, 'C', None]
>>> l[-3]
'C'
```

Simple factory functions can be created via lambda.

```
>>> l = defaultlist(lambda: 'empty')
>>> l[2] = "C"
>>> l[4]
'empty'
>>> l
['empty', 'empty', 'C', 'empty', 'empty']
```

It is also possible to implement advanced factory functions:

```
>>> def inc():
...     inc.counter += 1
...     return inc.counter
>>> inc.counter = -1
>>> l = defaultlist(inc)
>>> l[2] = "C"
>>> l
[0, 1, 'C']
>>> l[4]
4
>>> l
[0, 1, 'C', 3, 4]
```

**See the [Documentation](http://defaultlist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for any further details.**

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'defaultlist'

Which is weird because pip freeze shows that 1.0 is installed.

Answer (score 1):

One could implement a `defaultlist` that inherits from the `MutableSequence` abstract base class and wraps around the `defaultdict`. I do so in my [coinflip](https://pypi.org/project/coinflip/) package and expose it in the `coinflip.collections` submodule.

One would need to override the ABC like so:

```py
class defaultlist(MutableSequence):
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        ...

    def __setitem__(self, i, value):
        ...

    def __delitem__(self, i):
        ...

    def __len__(self):
        ...
        
    def insert(self):
        ...
```

I would initialise this `defaultlist` by mirroring the `defaultdict(default_factory=None)` method, passing `default_factory` to an internal private `defaultdict`.

Like with c0fec0de's solution, I would recommend filling the indices with `None` by default (i.e. pass in a "none factory" method), otherwise you will get a `KeyError` using unaccessed indices.

The accessor methods (get, set and delete items) would have indices just be keys in the private `defaultdict`, and update that dictionary accordingly when items are added and/or removed.

There are lesser-used aspects of the builtin `list` which, if one wishes to emulate, need some special considerations. I wrote more in-depth about the subject [here](https://blog.matthewbarber.io/2020/12/08/defaultlist/).

Answer (score -3):

One really simple way to do a defaultlist is with with a list comprehension and a range.

```
defaultvalue = "catfood"
x = [defaultvalue for i in range(0,4)]
```

which would result in

```
['catfood', 'catfood', 'catfood', 'catfood']
```

This could be a subclass, but doesn't need to be.
It could just be a factory function like this:

```
def defaultlist(defaultvalue, elementcount):
    return [defaultvalue for i in range(0, elementcount)]
```

and would work like this

```
defaultlist(None, 7)
```

returning this

```
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

Comment: I really don't think this is what the OP is after.