# defaultlist design

Tags: python, defaultdict

I am trying to create `defaultlist`, by analogy with `defaultdict`. The idea is that sometimes I want a list that is pre-filled (virtually!) with some element at all indices for which the value is not explicitly set. The difference with `defaultdict` is that I do not actually add the default values to the list, unless I have to extend list due to user assignments.

1) Is there any problem with this design?

2) This is the implementation I'm going to use. Is there any issue with it?

```
class defaultlist(list):
  def __init__(self, default_factory, arg = ()):
    # note: cannot use arg = None since list(None) is not the same as list()
    # alternatively can use:
    # def __init__(self, default_factory, *args, **kwargs)
    self.default_factory = default_factory
    super().__init__(arg)

  def __getitem__(self, key):
    try:
      return super().__getitem__(key)
    except IndexError:
      return self.default_factory()

  def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    for i in range(len(self), key):
      self.append(self.default_factory())
    self.append(value)
```

EDIT: Originally, I had two mistakes. Sorry, and thanks for pointing out both errors in the answers.

Comment: Why can't you just use a defaultdict with numeric keys?

Comment: @Keith: why doesn't Python ask you to use a `dict` with numeric keys and dump the pesky `list` the hell out of the language?

Comment: @EliBendersky That depends if your application needs to maintain some kind of ordered sequence. It's not clear from this question if that is really a requirement.

Comment: @Keith: I think you missed the irony in my previous comment

Comment: @EliBendersky It was missing the `<irony>` tag. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem.

1. Your `__init__` function tries to forward all arguments to the base class. However, the way you are writing it can only forward 1 argument, and the constructor will always expect the 2nd argument. The proper way to do that in Python is:

   ```
   def __init__(self, default_factory, *args, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.default_factory = default_factory
   ```
2. The `__setitem__` function tries to fill all not-yet-existing indices, but you have missed the `key` itself — note that `range` is exclusive in the end — therefore the `super().__setitem__` method will fail. You should use `.append` in that case.

   ```
   def __setitem__(self, key, value):
       try:
           super().__setitem__(key, value)
       except IndexError:
           for i in range(len(self), key):
               self.append(self.default_factory())
           self.append(value)
   ```

Comment: re: 1 - It's not clear to me that there is more than one argument expected here. `list` only takes one argument, so *args and **kwargs is probably unnecessary. But you're right that the constructor always expecting the second argument could be a problem, which is more easily solved by giving arg a default value.

Comment: @weronika: yes, you're right - either way would work (default or *args/**kwargs).

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason for your `TypeError` is just that you used `def` instead of `class` in the "`def defaultlist(list):`" line, so `defaultlist` is being treated like a function rather than a class.

Answer (score 1):

You are near the solution. You are mixing up the use of the super built-in function and the way argument packing is working. (NB: you got a typo in your question with def instead of class as @weronika pointed out, but your error message comes from your code being tested with class)

Try this:

```
class defaultlist(list):
  def __init__(self, default_factory, arg = ()):
    super(defaultlist, self).__init__(arg)
    self.default_factory = default_factory

  def __getitem__(self, key):
    try:
      return super(defaultlist, self).__getitem__(key)
    except IndexError:
      return self.default_factory()

  def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    for i in range(len(self), key):
      self.append(self.default_factory())
    super(defaultlist, self).__setitem__(key, value)

lst = defaultlist(int, [3, 4, 5])
```

Comment: I don't think there was anything wrong with the OP's version of argument unpacking - it'd just make the call `defaultlist(int, [3,4,5])`, which mimics the way `list` normally takes arguments, so I would say it's preferable to `defaultlist(int,3,4,5)`. You're right about `super()` not working, though.

Comment: @weronika agreed, I changed my answer to reflect your remark.

Answer (score 0):

There is another problem, if, for example, you wish to have a defaultlist of lists. The `__getitem__(..)` implementation as it stands will return a new list, but won't store it in the defaultlist.

The workaround is obvious, for example in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8749640/1143274